# Convert timestamp string to UTC date in bash

Tags: bash, date, timestamp, utc

I would like to rename my files with UTC timestamp. Currently those files are names based on local time (CET), as following, where first number if timestamp:

```
DataExport.test_20181029183500_300.csv.gz
```

For a reason I can not fix that at file source itself, so I have to perform a change later on.

Currently I extracted number with following:

```
echo "DataExport.test_20181029183500_300.csv.gz" | cut -d"_" -f2- | cut -c1-14
```

But now I am stuck here, how to continue.

Thank you and best regards

Comment: You can get the UTC date using this comand: `date -d "2018-10-29 18:35:00" +%s`

Comment: @Paplusc, thank you for feedback. I agree on this one, but is it somehow possible to convert straight from string above to "UTC" string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this as continuation of your code

```
date -d "$( echo "DataExport.test_20181029183500_300.csv.gz" | cut -d'_' -f2 | sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/g' )" +%s
```

Which will output:

```
1540809300
```

You can then use the output of that line to perform the renaming of your files. But I suggest if it gets to complex to just create a function or an actual script for that matter.

Here is a quick function to do just that:

```
function rename_ts() {

    filename="$1"
    time_stamp=$(echo "$filename" | cut -d'_' -f2)
    date_fmt=$(echo "$time_stamp" | sed 's/\(....\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)\(..\)/\1-\2-\3 \4:\5:\6/g')
    utc=$(date -d "$date_fmt" +%s)

    mv $filename $(echo "$filename" | sed "s/$time_stamp/$utc/g")

}
```

e.g. `rename_ts DataExport.test_20181029183500_300.csv.gz`

Comment: thank you very much for this, it almost did the trick. Only thing that I changed is that for new name I used old time format again by adding `ts_utc=$(date -u -d \@$utc +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S")` after definition of utc and used that in `sed` when moving file. Thank you very much!